# Problem on Archimedes' principle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, volume

I have to solve the following problem about the Archimedes' principle.

> Let a  cubic block of iron ($\rho_i$ = 7860 $kg / m^3$
> ) side 10.0 cm ($l_{cube}$) was placed in a tub of
> mercury ($\rho_m$= 13600 $kg / m^3$
> ) would it float or sink? If it floats, what is the height of the part
> immersed?

I think the block floats because $\rho_f<\rho_m$. Then I have thought that:
$$\rho_mVg-\rho_iV'g=0$$
where $V$ is the immersed volume in the mercury and $V'$ is the whole volume of the block.
So:
$l_{immersed}^3=\frac{\rho_i(l_{cube})^3}{\rho_m}=5.78cm^3\implies l_{immersed}=1.79cm.$

The book tells me that the result is $5.78 cm$ but I can't understand where I am doing a mistake.
Can you help me?

Comment: Hint: if the densities  wee equal what would be the answer?

Comment: $l_{immmersed}=10 cm$?

Comment: Oh I think I have understood my mistake! The volume of the immersed cube is $l_{immersed}l_{cube}^2$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mass of the whole iron cube is $m_i=V_i\cdot \rho_i=7860kg$.

In case of floating, the mass $m_i$ equals the mass $m_m$ of the mercury which is displaced.

The mass of the displaced mercury is $m_m=V_m\cdot\rho_m$, where $V_m=10\cdot 10 \cdot l_{immersed} $.
Therefore, $l_{immersed} =\frac{V_i\cdot \rho_i} {A\cdot \rho_m} = 5.78 cm^3$ as written in your book.

I don't know what "g" is in the formula you wrote first, but your mistake has surely something to do with the calculation of the immersed volume. The area stays the same, regardless, whether the cube is immersed or not. And the volume is the calculated as area times immersed hight.